# How can i initialize an array in Java?

Tags: java

This is my code in java. There is a problem at `System.out.println(averager(A));` . Java said that the Local variable A may not have been initialized.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averager {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to average?(2-4 only");
        int x;
        int[] A;
        x = input.nextInt();
        int Array4[]={input.nextInt(),input.nextInt(),input.nextInt(),input.nextInt()};
        int Array3[]={input.nextInt(),input.nextInt(),input.nextInt()};
        int Array2[]={input.nextInt(),input.nextInt()};
        if (x=='2'){
            A =Array2;
        }   
        else if (x=='3'){
            A = Array3;
        }
        else if (x=='4'){
            A= Array4;                  
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }           
        System.out.println(averager(A)); // Error
    }


    public static int averager(int...numbers){
        int total=0;
        for(int x:numbers){
            total+=x;
         }
           return total/numbers.length;         
        }               
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at  your code and consider what happens if `x` is not `'2'`, `'3'`, or `'4'`. What is `A` as of the

```
System.out.println(averager(A));
```

line?

Right! You've never given it a value. That's what the compiler is warning you about.

Comment: Lets say x is either 2,3 or 4. This will cause A to be either Array2 , Array3 or Array4 isnt it ??? And then it goes into the averager. Well anyway, i have to be wrong since my code didn't work. How do i solve it ??

Comment: @CactusHam: Again: What if `x` is **not** `'2'`, `'3'`, or `'4'`? The compiler is warning you that you're using `A` when it may not have ever been initialized. So what do you figure you need to do to fix it? What would you do to solve the problem of *not initializing* `A` in the `else` case?

Comment: @KishoreKumarNaidu: Arrays being fixed size has nothing whatsoever to do with the problem. This error would occur with an `int` variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java can be initialized `= null` because if the code doesn't enter an if statements A is never set. Also if by chance you already know the dimensions of the array you can initialize it like this:

```
int[] A = new int[numberofelements];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

It reads 9 (4 + 3 + 2) numbers always from STDIN (in Array4 to Array2 part).

What you want to do probably is

```
    int x = input.nextInt();
    int[] A = new int[x];
    for ( int i = 0; i < x; ++i ) A[i] = input.nextInt();
```

But if you want to solve only "Local variable A may not have been initialized." warning, return (end the program) after printing the error

```
    else {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code as

```
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int[] A= new int[x];
```

Answer (score -1):

Change: int[] A = null;

Change : `int x` to `int x = 0;`. You need to initialize variables in java.